# Does GridToolbar work in XGrid? (React / Material-UI )

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, xgrid

Is it possible to use GridToolbar in XGrid? Sandbox gives error message: "Cannot read property 'current' of undefined" when testing this.

[Code in demo.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28Pa6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing GridToolbar from '@material-ui/data-grid', try importing GridToolbar from '@material-ui/x-grid'.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { GridToolbar, XGrid } from "@material-ui/x-grid";
import { useDemoData } from "@material-ui/x-grid-data-generator";

export default function ToolbarGrid() {
  const { data } = useDemoData({
    dataSet: "Commodity",
    rowLength: 100,
    maxColumns: 6
  });

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
      <XGrid
        {...data}
        components={{
          Toolbar: GridToolbar
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```